# Passing in a Class dynamically

Tags: java

Hopefully quite a simple question.  How do I pass in a Class into an abstract method?

My abstract method is as follows:

```
public abstract class IDataList {

    public LinkedList<IThing> getRows(IThing thing, String sql, List<Object> vals) throws Exception {
        LinkedList<IThing> list = new LinkedList<>();
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> rows = db.executeSelect(sql, vals);
        for (HashMap<String, Object> row : rows) {
            list.add(new thing(row));
        }
        rowCount = (long) getDb().executeScalar("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        return list;
    }
}
```

Which is inherited by a concrete class:

```
public class DataList extends IDataList {

}
```

The IThing is currently an empty abstract class which is extended by an Thing, for example:

```
public class Thing extends IThing {

    private long uid;
    private String name;

    public Thing(HashMap<String, Object> row) {
        this.uid = (long) row.get("uid");
        this.name = (String)row.get("name");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to pass in Thing into a concrete class of IDataList, for example:

```
IDataList dataList = new DataList();
dataList.getRows(Thing, "select something", new ArrayList<>())
```

Comment: `Object` is an unfortunate choice of class name for your example.

Comment: haha yeah. I appreciate that :p  Changing it now.

Comment: the constructor should match class name so change both either to Thing or Item

Comment: You don't have any abstract method in `IDataList`.
The class is abstract but it could be concrete as implementation of it adds nothing.

Comment: @Gal Sorry, missed that during the refactoring :/  Good spot.

Comment: @davidxxx  there is more in there that I havent included to not lose focus of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Thing` Class as a Row->Object mapper, it will be better to use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper`

```
public class CustomerRowMapper implements RowMapper {
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustId(rs.getInt("CUST_ID"));
        customer.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
        customer.setAge(rs.getInt("AGE"));
        return customer;
    }

}

public Customer findByCustomerId(int custId) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?";
    Customer customer = (Customer)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { custId }, new CustomerRowMapper());
    return customer;
}
```

Comment: @Christian, if so, then do not pass "IThing thing" into getRows, just return it.

Comment: I works in a similar way to that already but I thought I could move methods around to stop repeating code. It feels wrong though so I guess I'll go back to that RowMapper way.